# How do I perform a permutation in R with fixed objects in a nucleotide string?

Tags: r

I need to see all possible variations of these nucleotide string: GCGCT**AA**GC**AAAAAA**CAT
with two caveats: 
1. everything that is not **Bold** is fixed
2. **Bold** can be either A or C

I used the permutations function:

```
library(gtools)
x <- c('a', 'c')
permutations(n=2, r=8, v=x, repeats.allwed=T)
```

It works, the problem is that I would need the list of results to be in the nucleotide sequence, or else I will spend more time copying and pasting the results in the nucleotide sequence than doing the permutation by hand.
Thanks a lot!!!
Giacomo

Comment: Welcome to SO. How flexible does the solution need to be? Are the "permutable" subsequences always of length 2 and 6 and always in these positions or there are some more general rules to identify them? The more fixed things are the easier the solution would tend to be.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `sprintf`:

```
library(gtools)
x <- c('a', 'c')
p <- permutations(n=2, r=8, v=x, repeats.allowed=T)

#split columns
p <- asplit(p, 2)

#insert into format string
do.call(sprintf, c(p, fmt = "GCGCT%s%sGC%s%s%s%s%s%sCAT"))
#[1] "GCGCTaaGCaaaaaaCAT" "GCGCTaaGCaaaaacCAT" "GCGCTaaGCaaaacaCAT" "GCGCTaaGCaaaaccCAT" "GCGCTaaGCaaacaaCAT" ...
```

You might want to create the permutations from upper-case letters.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, resulting in a matrix with each line being a permutation

```
library(gtools)
x <- c('A', 'C')
perms <- permutations(n = 2, r = 8, v = x, repeats.allowed = TRUE)

nucleotid <- c("G", "C", "G", "C", "T", "A",
               "A", "G", "C", "A", "A", "A", 
               "A", "A", "A", "C", "A", "T") 

# Looping throught each permutation to create the string
result <- apply(perms, 1, function(x){
  y <- nucleotid
  y[c(6,7,10:15)] <- x
  y
})
t(result)
```

Comment: Thanks! It works very well, I just decided to use the other method because it gets rid authomatically of the "" (easier to confront with the gene sequence)